# Once paid yearly - is in normal?

Tags: grammar, word-choice, sentence-choice

Is it correct to say

> Once paid yearly you have...(many advantages)

? Or would be better to unfold it to

> Once you pay early you have...

or

> Paid yearly once...

Meaning that it's said to a person who chooses a payment period in order to persuade him to select annual payment. The advantages result from the fact of the paying for an year, no matter if a user would cancel the subscription for next year.

Comment: Perhaps you want to say: *If you pay on a yearly basis / on an annual basis // If you make an annual payment, ...*

Comment: Hmm.. I want to say _If you make at least one annual payment_ and I'd like to say it more shortly.

Comment: You could say something like: *One annual payment will allow you to ...*

Comment: If you're determined to use **once**, you could say, "Once you make your first annual payment, you will get...." The important thing is that you tie **once** to a thing that happens one time only: for example, the **first** annual payment.

Comment: Each of your sentences means something different.

Answer (score 0):

It may be best to say "With an annual subscription, you gain...". This makes it clear that there are benefits that you gain when paying with the yearly subscription. The use of "subscription" means that the purchase is cancel-able, like all subscriptions, and avoids directly suggesting paying for one year and canceling, which may lead to more cancellations.

This may be a bit outside the scope of the question, but if this is to be used to compare the differences of a yearly vs monthly subscription, you could use a table with checkbox especially to avoid this issue altogether, something along these lines but with subscription lengths along the top:

[image: Image of sample table]